# How can I insert new row in a table using Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate

I'm trying to understand JPA/Hibernate, I'm able to create new database but I don't understand how insert new row in my 
database.
This is the code:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String adress;
    private String phoneNumber;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setAdress(String adress) {
        this.adress = adress;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getAdress() {
        return adress;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

   @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Person)) {
            return false;
        }
        Person other = (Person) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "entinty.Person[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }


}
```

The class that create the database is:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Person p = new Person();
        p.setName("xxx");
        p.setAdress("yyy");
        p.setPhoneNumber("zzz");
        EntityManagerFactory emf = javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("testPU");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        try {
            em.persist(p);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            em.getTransaction().rollback();
        }

        em.close();
        emf.close();



    }

}
```

At this point I have a table with one row (with written "xxx-yyy-zzz"). How can I add new row? Creating new Person doesn't work because it creates new table... I only find solution using Session and SessionFactory but I'm not able to use it, because I can't understand how generate a hibernate.cfg.xml (and in general how to create a session object).
Is There a solution using only EntityManager? Or how can I generate/write a hibernate.cfg.xml file? Is there a way to generate automatically it using netbeans?

EDIT: this is my persistence.xml file. Where do I have to put the ? I put it in the *** zone but it doesn't work...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="testPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>test.Person</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/stackoverflow?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="leonida95."/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    *****
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: what tables are generated?

Comment: How can em.persist re-create a table? This code works even for multiple persist.

Comment: a tables with the person with name xxx,  adress yyy and phone zzz. 
How can I insert a row with name aaa address bbb and phone ccc? (If I try to create a person p2 and run em.persist(p); em.persist(p2) I get an error, since there already exists a table "Person".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your *Persistence Unit* file you'll have something like

```
<properties>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="..." />
   <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="..."/>
   ...
</properties>
```

To create tables when the `EntityManagerFactory` is constructed, just add

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
```

---

Your code works fine.

You can call `persist` as many times as you want, and it will add rows to the target table.

```
em.persist(person1);
em.persist(person2);
...
```

`persist` does not create a table.

Comment: I'm Trying but it doesn't work... I post the persistence.xml file in the EDIT, could you help me?

Comment: Could you post the code which fails? I mean, the code where you call persist multiple times.

Comment: adding your line in the persistence.xml produce this error Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to execute JPA schema generation create command [create table Person (id bigint not null auto_increment, adress varchar(255), name varchar(255), phoneNumber varchar(255), primary key (id))]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'person' already exists.

Comment: oh wait. Now it work. probably I made some mistake erlier forgotting something. Dunno. Thank you very much.

Comment: @MicheleBattagliola and remember to check the Hibernate documentation about hbm2ddl.auto https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html under "Table 3.7. Miscellaneous Properties"